# MIPS (assembly) Print function not working as expected

Tags: assembly, mips, low-level, mips32, mips64

I'm learning MIPS and trying to understand function calls and stuff. I wrote this basic 'printValue' function to print the value of a variable defined in Global memory, but it's printing 0 instead (it should print '2', as a2 is initialized) and I can't understand why. Here's my code:

```
.data

    # Allocate variables in global memory
    a2:
        .word 2
    a1:
        .word 3
    a0: 
        .word 5 
    x:
        .word 0
    result:
        .word 0

    output_msg:
        .asciiz "The result is "
    newl:
        .asciiz "\n"
    
.align 2

.text
        
.globl main

main:

    #prologue (push stack space)
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  

    la $a0, a2
    jal printValue

    #epilogue
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4
    
    # Signal end of program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
        
printValue: 
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # Allocate space on the stack
    
    # Print value
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall
    
    jr $ra
```

Where is it going wrong? Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You never set `$s0`, so `move $a0, $s0` copies a zero to the arg for your print-int call.  You can see this with a debugger if you set a breakpoint there.  If you want to load a pointed-to value, `lw $a0, 0($a0)`

Comment: For future reference, don't use label names that are so similar to register names.

Comment: You're passing global variable a2 by reference, are  you sure that's what you wanted to do?  It would be more normal for such a print function to take a value to print rather than an address to dereference to print.  Why?  Because that would make it more general purpose: then you could print a value from a register or from memory, not just from memory.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks for the tip about naming conventions! Definitely makes sense. As for the global variable, im not sure actually haha. I have to do an assignment that multiplies 3 numbers together inside a function (this was just practice for it), and it specifies the variables have to be global. But I have such a hard time understandings MIPS, what do you mean "by value" vs an address? Would that be like "move $a0, a2" or something? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, you can't do `move $a0, a2` but you can do `lw $a0, a2`.  The caller would do that.  By value function arguments simply pass the arguments value: so in `f(x)` x's value is passed.  The C equivalent to by reference is `g(&x)`, meaning (1) x has to have an address in memory, and (2) that address is the parameter.  With the by-value you can do `f(x+2)` without having to store `x+2` into memory, because `f` doesn't need the address.